# Detect rectangular table from ASUS Xtion Live Pro IR image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have an IR image with a resolution of `(240 x 320)`, datatype: `float32` as you can see here:
[image: ir]
The raw `npy` image is [here](https://cloud.univ-grenoble-alpes.fr/index.php/s/EtpEaGtg6dcW98B).

My objective is to detect the table (brown contour) in order to crop this region as a ROI.

What I have tried so far is to do:

1. **Histogram equalization** to increase contrast,
2. **Gaussian Blurring** to reduce the noise, and
3. **contour detection** to find the rectangular table in the middle of the image.

Note that the table in my case is installed on wheels, and hence it might slightly move so I want to detect it dynamically, and not use its fixed position inside the image.

The code I have used is:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import random as rng

path = ""
# Read the numpy array
ir_raw = np.load(path+"ir.npy") # (240, 320) float32

ir = np.uint8((ir_raw/ir_raw.max()) * 255)
# Histogram equalization (Contrast Adjustment)
heq_ir = cv2.equalizeHist(ir)
# Gaussian smoothing (Noise Removal)
g_blur_ir = cv2.GaussianBlur(heq_ir, (5,5), 0)

# Otsu Thresholding
_, thresh_ir = cv2.threshold(g_blur_ir, 120, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + 
                                            cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
# Find contours
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh_ir, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Draw contours
rng.seed(12345)

drawing = np.zeros((thresh_ir.shape[0], thresh_ir.shape[1], 3), dtype=np.uint8)

for i in range(len(contours)):
    color = (rng.randint(0,256), rng.randint(0,256), rng.randint(0,256))
    cv2.drawContours(drawing, contours, i, color, 2, cv2.LINE_8, hierarchy, 0)


plt.subplot(121)
plt.imshow(heq_ir)
plt.title("IR")

plt.subplot(122)
plt.imshow(drawing)
plt.title("IR contours")

plt.show()
```

Can you please tell me how can I detect the rectangular table in order to crop it as a **ROI**? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the following, the table always has same area (well duh) but in the case below its always the largest object detected (the code should be easily to amend to filter out objects of different areas though).

I've filtered out all contours that have a different area to the table contour (process of elimination until I found the table then set the area threshold accordingly) & then fitted a rectangle to that contour. It is possible to fit skewed rectangles in OpenCV as well but I havent in this case. (EDIT: code for skewed rectangles added)

Your ROI boundary is in `boundRect`

```
for i in range(len(contours)):
    
    if cv2.contourArea(contours[i]) > 10000:
        
        color = (rng.randint(0,256), rng.randint(0,256), rng.randint(0,256))
        cv2.drawContours(drawing, contours, i, color, 2, cv2.LINE_8, hierarchy, 0)

        # For unrotated bounding rectangle
        boundRect = cv2.boundingRect(contours[i])
        cv2.rectangle(drawing, (int(boundRect[0]), int(boundRect[1])), (int(boundRect[0]+boundRect[2]), int(boundRect[1]+boundRect[3])), (255, 255, 255), 2)

        # For minimal bounding rectangle that will rotate with table rotation
        rect = cv2.minAreaRect(contours[i])
        box = cv2.boxPoints(rect) 
        box = np.int0(box)
        cv2.drawContours(drawing, [box], 0, (255, 0, 255), 2)

        print(cv2.contourArea(contours[i]))
```

Ouput,

[image]

Comment: The drawn rectangle is larger than the table, I tried to do `cv2.rectangle(heq_ir, (int(boundRect[0]), int(boundRect[1])), (int(boundRect[0]+boundRect[2]), int(boundRect[1]+boundRect[3])), (255, 255, 255), 2)` and it shows that the rectangle doesn't fit the table precisely, and this solution doesn't solve the table rotation problem.

Comment: @Bilal I have added the code that should deal with the table rotation. As for the bounding box being larger than your table, well that is a limitation of using contours, as your found contour isnt rectangular ie the rough edge on the left. Hough lines might be the way to go.